# how to handle %20 in Link URL

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router-dom

recently I found a weird problem
I use Link from react-router-dom for products page and wrote that code:

```
<Link to={` /product/${product._id}`}>
  <img src={product.image} />
</Link>
```

and in app page this code:

```
<Route path="/product/:id" component={Products} />
```

and everything must goes in correct way but,, but in URL I see this shit :

```
/%20/product/1
```

and I have no idea why %20 appear !!

Comment: That means there’s a space in the path. 20 is the ascii value for space

Comment: Probably the space in the beginning of the /product

Comment: %20 is ASCII code for space which gets added to the urls

Comment: Looks to be a typo in the link path, you've `to={\` /product/${product._id}\`}` with a leading space. Try removing that space to `to={\`/product/${product._id}\`}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **BrowserRouter** and facing this issue then you should pass an empty string to the prop **basename** so for example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as AppRouter, ... } from "react-router-dom";

const RouterComponent = () => (
<AppRouter basename="">
...
</AppRouter>
)
```

Passing an empty string should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you use space before /product

```
<Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
  <img src={product.image} />
</Link>
```